# WPF exits in InitializeComponent(), no error, can't debug

Tags: wpf

I have an app that used to work well, I did some modifications and such. Now, only about 1/2 the time it runs. I installed the app to a laptop and it doesn't run at all.

There are no errors, warnings, or ui shown by the task bar shows the app momentarily.

Even when I run inside visual studio and put a break point on InitalizeComponent(), I can't seem to locate anything causing the problem.

My code essentially looks like this:

```
        Application.Current.DispatcherUnhandledException += Current_DispatcherUnhandledException;
        this.Dispatcher.UnhandledException += Dispatcher_UnhandledException;
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        log("Initalizing....");
```

This is wpf 4 in vs2015. Any ideas how to get some type of error message before it exits and figure out what is causing the problem? The app works fine once it actually runs. The event viewer on the laptop shows some messages, something about faulting in KernalBase.... nothing useful.

I'm not sure if InitalizeComponent() is the issue, but when I put a BP on it and step through the code, it always exits at that point.

Comment: To break on more exceptions in Visual Studio press Ctrl+Alt+E and tick all checkboxes. And step inside InitializeComponent when debugging

Answer (score 1):

As @Breeze mentioned, you need to strengthen the exceptions, like that:

Go to Debug -> Exceptions... **OR** Ctrl+Alt+E and you'll see this window:

[image: Exceptions window]

Mark this two:

Common Language Runtime Exceptions and
Manage Debbugging Assistants.

**REMEMBER** after finish using them unmark them because it also throws exceptions you don't need to deal with a lot of times.